# How do I fix the blurry text in linux terminal (nvidia)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, nvidia, virtual-console

The linux console (e.g. ctrl-alt-f2) on my ubuntu 22.04 install is blurry, while my displays report 4k resolution coming via display port.

I'd like to have a crisper text and more console space. It looks like an upscaled low resolution framebuffer, but I wonder why my display still claims 4k. There is also noticable flickering when going to the virtual console, so maybe the DP resolution information is incorrect or there are components switching back and forth resolutions.

There is various information on the net to get the display to some specific resolution from bootloader, but it seems unreliable or outdated with every new nvidia driver version supporting a new kernel API.

So before I go down a rabbithole of grub parameters, linux kernel parameters, initramfs module inclusion lists etc, as of 22.04 and nvidia 510.60, what is the right way to get better/native resolution on linux console tty?

Comment: Have you tried updating the video driver?

Comment: 510.60 is the current Nvidia driver.

Comment: did you figure this out? same issue